# How to get an exact size frame from image produced by AVCaptureSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

[image]

I am working on an application that captures a specific view inside of AVCaptureSession as the image above shows.

I am using `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` to capture an image in `AVCaptureSession`. The problem is I am getting an image with a specific size which is, ({2448, 3264}). My solution is to convert this image to the same frame of my background view in order to have the same coordinates and frame.

Using `imageWithImage`, I used the same frame I used for my captureView and everything works out pretty well. The resizedImage ended up being {768, 1024} which is the same size of the AVCaptureSession.

From here on out, based on this coordinates, I attempted to crop an image using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` based on the captureView's frame which is the green view.

The output image that I got was off. My question is there a better method to use than `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to capture the exact view that I want from the image that I get back from AVCaptureSession? Is there a better way to do what I am trying to implement? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
  AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
                videoConnection = connection;

                //Handle orientation for video

                if(videoConnection.supportsVideoOrientation)
                {
                    if(captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ){
                        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
                    }
                    if(captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ){
                        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight;
                    }
                    if(captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ){
                        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        UIImage *resizedImage = [weakSelf imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:outputImageView.frame.size];

        //Image view to test screenshot of AVCaptureSession
        outputImageView.image = resizedImage;

        //Screenshot of captureView frame (green view)
        CGRect captureFrame = captureView.frame;

        CGImageRef cropRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(resizedImage.CGImage, captureFrame);
        UIImage* cropImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cropRef];

// Image view to test cropped image
        sampleImageView.image = cropImage;

        //Hide Indicator
        [weakSelf hideActivityView];

    }];

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Method used to capture image.

Comment: did you try `videoGravity` of
 `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`

Comment: @MikeAlter Yes, it's currently set to AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect. Changing the video gravity doesn't change the size of the image I'm getting back from AVCaptureSession using AVCaptureStillImageOutput. I want to be able set the frame of AVCaptureStillImageOutput to a specific frame. This line of code  "captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = cameraView.frame;"                                                                                                                                        to set AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the pixel scaling to 1.0 as the comments say.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 1.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```